# MongoDB - Deleting 1 million records taking very high time

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have more than 10 million records in collection. Out of which i have to delete 1 million records.
I am using indexed fields in query filter.

Below query is taking 150+ sec to delete 1 Million records. How to optimize below query to get less response time.

```
db.CollectionData.bulkWrite([{ deleteMany: { "filter": { "client_id": "8", "collection_id": "156643", "version": {"$lt": 7}}}}]);
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Is a delete rate of 7k records/second really particularly slow?

Comment: Is this a one time run, or a continual process that is likely to repeat?  If this is a repeating process you might consider changing the way you store data to address this use case.  If you want to repeat this process at any particular regularity you could store the data in a way the data to be mass deleted is combined and isolated in a collection.  Dropping a collection is trivial, and easy on the replication framework (again - assuming you have a replica set).  But this strategy is based on how you store the data in anticipation of deleting data.

Comment: if you have compound index with all this 3 fields i guess it will be fast.Looking the index alone will be enough to find the deleted documents.(like coverage of query from index)

Answer (score -1):

You should learn how to analyze your MongoDB queries. There are some methods available to get insights about the performance statistics of the query and much more. There is a nice tutorial in the MongoDB docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/

With this additional information, you should be able to identify your problem, if you have one.

Btw, this has nothing to do with Java...